# JS carrito de compras: no se eliminan productos correctamente del carrito

Tags: javascript

estoy teniendo un problema en JS al momento de querer eliminar productos de un carrito de compras (por primera vez hago uno lateral): si tengo por ejemplo 3 productos y quiero eliminar el segundo, no puedo hacerlo hasta no haber eliminado el primero:

```
let shoppingCart = [];

const showCart = () => {

// Clear all the items from the cart before showing the cart again and preventing to replicate the products with every click on the cart btn

modalContainer.innerHTML = " ";

shoppingCart.forEach((product) => {

    // Modal content (products added)

    let cartContent = document.createElement("div");
    cartContent.className = "modal-content p-2";
    cartContent.innerHTML = `

<div class="cart__products__container">

<img src = "${product.img}" alt= "${product.name}" class="img-fluid img__product__cart "/>

<h3 class="p-2"> ${product.name} </h3>
<p class="p-2"> $ ${product.price} </p>
<span class= "d-flex justify-content-center" id="delete"> X </span>

</div>
`
    modalContainer.append(cartContent);

    const closeBtnProduct = document.getElementById("delete");
    
    // Event listener to the X in the cart to delete a product

    closeBtnProduct.addEventListener("click", deleteProduct);

});

};

// Adding the event listener to show the cart with the function showCart

showShoppingCart.addEventListener("click", showCart);

// Delete product from the cart

const deleteProduct = () => {

// First find the product's id that the user wants to delete from the cart

const findProductsId = shoppingCart.find((element) => element.id);

// Read every element on the cart and leave those when their id is different from the product the user wants to delete

shoppingCart = shoppingCart.filter((cartId) => {

    return cartId !== findProductsId;
});

showCart();

};
```

Otra variante del botón X para eliminar un producto elegido que intenté fue:

```
 shoppingCart.forEach((product) => {

    // Modal content (products added)

    let cartContent = document.createElement("div");
    cartContent.className = "modal-content p-2";
    cartContent.innerHTML = `

<div class="cart__products__container">

<img src = "${product.img}" alt= "${product.name}" class="img-fluid img__product__cart "/>

<h3 class="p-2"> ${product.name} </h3>
<p class="p-2"> $ ${product.price} </p>

// Omití crear el span con la X para hacerlo por separado más abajo

</div>
`
  modalContainer.append(cartContent);

    // Opción alternativa para el btn X de eliminar producto del carrito

    const closeBtnProduct = document.createElement("span");
    closeBtnProduct.className = "d-flex justify-content-center";
    closeBtnProduct.innerText = "X";
    modalContainer.append(closeBtnProduct);

   closeBtnProduct.addEventListener("click", deleteProduct);
```

Y aún así me elimina correctamente el primer producto del carrito, y con el resto me elimina un producto diferente al que elegí.
Alguna idea de qué  está fallando con el botón de eliminar productos?

Comment: Deberías pasar como argumento qué id querés eliminar, por que o sino, ¿cómo se sabría qué elemento se está queriendo eliminar?

Comment: @padaleiana mil gracias!!! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay varios puntos a revisar.

1. tu método deleteProduct no recibe ningún parámetro y ese debería ser el id del producto a eliminar.
2. Dentro del borrar, el **find** no esta comparando contra ningún valor deseado (el cual seria el id), solo valida que no sea **null**, por ende el valor que siempre retornara será el primero.

```js
let deleteProduct= (id) =>{
  cart = cart.filter(e => e.id != id);
}
```

y cuando le agregas el onclick al elemento te debería quedar así:
`closeBtnProduct.addEventListener("click", deleteProduct(product.id);`

espero que te sirva
saludos

Comment: muchísimas gracias!! ^^